# AJax call of URL within jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to simply invoke a URL like 'comment/comment_id/promote_to_front'.
How do I do that? 
I've tried something like the following with no luck(this promotes a static id:13):

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'comment/13/promote_to_front',
});
```

I do not want to to manipulate any returned data. Simply trying to call the url.

Comment: First off, type should be post

Comment: @megawac: Why? User's not providing content (that I can see) to the controller (other than 13, but that's part of the route itself). -- OP: You may want to use `/comment/13/promote_to_front` (an absolute path) for instances where it's being called by a page outside of the root.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please be more precise

Comment: Do you want to put the info somewhere?

Comment: @BradChristie Because you're changing data on the server. Get is used exclusively for getting data from the server - which you are not doing here

Comment: @megawac Totally incorrect.  `GET` passes variables to the server via querystring.  `POST` passes variables to the server as post data (so not visible in the querystring).  They *both* have the ability to send and/or receive data.

Comment: @Archer Sure you can accomplish the same ends using get or post as they both can get sent with data. However, from my understanding of restful architecture it is a bad practice to make any form of server update with a get request by convention even if it is possible.

Comment: @megawac That's correct - it's bad practice, but that's a very different statement than `Get is used exclusively for getting data from the server`.  No matter - apples and oranges :)

Comment: @Archer also I should add that get requests can be cached unlike a post.

Comment: @megawac Yes, that's right, as the data is passed in the URL, as I said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass other details sometimes, it's just a guess. If you can show the server side code then we can come to some conclusion, but anyways here are some additional things which you should try:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <your url>,
        data: <if any>,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg, textStatus, XMLHTTPRequest) {
           //Some Code
        },
        error: function (XMLHTTPRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Some handler
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

It has lots of extra thing, which you even dont want, just try to add the options one by one.

Comment: It's not invoking the URL. When I try to just copy paste the URL like "www.mysite.com/comment/13/promote_to_front" it still does not work. I'll try your solution.

Comment: Sure, let us know the output of your try.

Answer (score 1):

Add a callback function to get the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "comment/13/promote_to_front"
}).done(function(data) {
   //DO stuff with you data.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/